# Evaluating different blocks under a common binding

Tags: ruby, block, eval

I want each module to carry a common binding environment, within which it can evaluate different blocks. I have code like this intended to do so:

```
class Module
  def config &pr
    @binding ||= binding
    @binding.eval("pr.call")
  end
end
```

Given this, (I thought) I can call different blocks under a common binding:

```
class A; end
A.config{a = 3}
A.config{a} # => 3
```

But it seems that the `pr` inside the string passed to `eval` is fixed to the `pr` when it was called for the first time, so from the second time, it does not matter what block is passed; always the initial block is evaluated:

```
A.config{a = 3}
A.config{} # => 3
A.config{:foo} # => 3
```

How can I make the given block be evaluated each time as follows?

```
A.config{a = 3}
A.config{} # => nil
A.config{:foo} # => :foo
A.config{a} # => 3
```

Comment: Evaluating `pr.call` won’t add any of the local variables used in the block to the binding, they are scoped to the block. It will only add `pr`. You can achieve what you’re after if you pass _strings_ to the `config` method but I don’t think you can do it with blocks.